# Python だと "ab"*3 -> "ababab" のように書けますが、C++ではどう書けますか？

Tags: c++

Python だと `"ab"*3 -> "ababab"` のように書けますが、C++ではどう簡潔に書けますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

関数を定義してみるのもよいかもしれません。

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
 
std::string repeat_string(const std::string &text, int n) {
  if (n <= 0) return "";
  std::string repeated;
  repeated.reserve(n*text.length());
  for(;n;--n, repeated += text);
  return repeated;
}
 
int main() {
  std::cout << repeat_string("ab", 3) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！自分で作るしかないですかね…

Answer (score 0):

サードパーティライブラリ[Range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html)を利用して、ワンライナー風に記述することもできはします。（技巧的なコードですし、あまりお薦めはしません...）

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
// Range-v3 Library
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
namespace rng = ranges; 

int main() {
  std::string s = "ab";
  size_t n = 3;

  std::string result = rng::views::repeat_n(s, n) | rng::views::join | rng::to<std::string>();

  std::cout << result;
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/9Efc3fnb3

また、2023年改定の次期C++23標準ライブラリには同等機能[`repeat(s, n)`](https://wg21.link/p2474)や[`to<string>()`](https://wg21.link/p1206r7)が取り込まれる見込みです。

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>  // C++23
namespace rng = std::ranges; 

int main() {
  std::string s = "ab";
  size_t n = 3;

  std::string result = rng::views::repeat(s, n) | rng::views::join | rng::to<std::string>();

  std::cout << result;
}
```